# Making new commands

Tags: line

I want to write my own library.  How could one define a new command equivalent to the following ?

```
\par\noindent\rule[5pt]{\textwidth}{1pt}
```

Comment: Welcome, you can wrap most macro sequences into a `newcommand` macro. In your case e.g. `\newcommand{\commandname}{\par\noindent\rule[5pt]{\textwidth}{1pt}}` where you can exchange `\commandname` with your preference. If that makes sense with your code, is another question, because we don't know your exact use case. Instead of posting just a code snippet, a compilable MWE, which shows your aims, would help.

Comment: `commandname` do not allow hyphens `-` or underscores `_` ?

Comment: Digits, too. As is generally the case with LaTeX. They are case sensitive, however, so you can some things with CamelCase.

Comment: No digits as well ?

Comment: The resulting names then end up looking like the trains in india !

Comment: Not necessarily, you can also use very short command names, as long as they're not already defined. In this case `newcommand` will give a warning/error.

Comment: @Bhanat, my impression is, you try Latex unsystematically. May I ask you: which (introductory) books are you reading about Latex?

Comment: What about going through https://www.learnlatex.org ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer is the one from my comment:

you can wrap most macro sequences into a `newcommand` macro. In your case e.g. `\newcommand{\commandname}{\par\noindent\rule[5pt]{\textwidth}{1pt}}` where you can exchange `\commandname` with your preference.

At the regular user level command names can't contain hyphens, underscores an other special characters.

Of course, there are many possibilities more to define new commands, like `\NewDocumentCommand`, simple `\def` or `expl3` variants.

But for your simple use case `\newcommand` seems best for me.

Comment: (And that‘s all documented in a good book introducing into Latex. Sigh …)

Comment: And, not to mention, several good and detailed documentation's, countless posts on TeX.SE and other webpages, as well as further books. Of course, my answer is just one obvious possibility.

Comment: I read a book, but I am extremely old (pre-latex, pre-ams) and things have changed too much since then.

Comment: Ok, was it about TeX? // Please select any of the books I posted in my previous comments to your questions, be it in-print or electronic. The basic ideas of LaTeX aren't that difficult, even brilliant in a way. The problem comes from its variety; packages both simplify and complicate things. But as with speaking foreign languages, once you've got used to it, things start becoming easier.

Comment: Yes, it was plain tex. Is mathtools also part of the LaTeX3 Project ?

Comment: If you're more used to plain TeX, you could also use primitives like `\def` for defining new commands/macros.

Comment: @Bhanat you do not need to ask just look at the copyright and maintainer lines at https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools

Comment: Very well then.  Felicitations.